# CSS selecting classes with different ids and vice versa

Tags: html, css

As you can see the CSS code below is repetitive but I am not fluent enough to simplify it.

```
<!-- CLASS then ID -->
.myClass#firstID {
    background-color: #bbb;
}   

.myClass#secondID {
    background-color: #bbb;
}   
.myClass#firstID:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}   

.myClass#secondID:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}   

<!-- ID then CLASS -->
#myID.firstClass {
    background-color: #123456;
}   

#myID.secondClass {
    background-color: #123456;
}   
#myID.firstClass:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}   

#myID.secondClass:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

Is there a way to stylize a class with multiple ids or an id with multiple classes in a single block without repeating ".myClass" or "#myID"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided code is equivalent to this:

```
.myClass#firstID, .myClass#secondID {
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

.myClass#firstID:hover, .myClass#secondID:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}   

#myID.firstClass, #myID.secondClass {
    background-color: #123456;
}

#myID.firstClass:hover, #myID.secondClass:hover{
    background-color: #111;
}
```

It cannot be condensed much further.

Additionally, [Sass provides nested selector functionality](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3).

Answer (score 0):

seperate each id with a comma.

```
    .myClass#firstID ,.myClass#secondID,
#myID.firstClass, #myID.secondClass {
    background-color: #123456;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole point of a `class`; you group similar groups under a classname, and unique items under `id`. So your css should look like:

```
.myClass {
    background-color: #bbbbbb
}

.myClass:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

I don't understand why you'd want to refer to a div with both its class and id. Unless I am missing something else here.

Comment: I am using using different buttons in JQuery to collapse a <div> with specific ID but belonging to a similar class. I don't want one button to collapse every <div>. There are other stylizing details that I omitted. I might have given a bad example. But the gist of my question is more about syntax than semantics.

Answer (score 0):

```
#firstID, #secondID {
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
}   
#firstID:hover, #secondID:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same class or ID on multiple area where you want to achieve the same style property. Hope that answers your question.

```css
#myid{
 background-color: purple;
}

.myclass{
 color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div id="myid">
  <p class="myclass">your contend to be styled</p>
 </div>

 <div id="myid">
  <p class="myclass">Youe second contend to be styled</p>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: I was asking along the lines of if there were two ".myClass" elements each with different IDs, if there is a way to select both IDs with ".myClass" in a single block.

Comment: @Dobob then you can use #myid, .myclass{ your attribute } hope this helps.